# Change data-path threesixty plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using threesixty plugin (jQuery) to display an 360 degrees view of an car.

```
<div class="threesixty" data-path="img/volvo/test/car{index}.jpg" data-count="6"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">


           var $threeSixty = $('.threesixty');

                $threeSixty.threeSixty({
                    dragDirection: 'horizontal',
                    useKeys: false,
                    draggable: true
                });

 </script>
```

I want to use select boxes to change the car shown, so users can pick their own car they want to see.

I tried to use the .change function to call a .data function to change the path.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


           var $threeSixty = $('.threesixty');

                $threeSixty.threeSixty({
                    dragDirection: 'horizontal',
                    useKeys: false,
                    draggable: true
                });

                $( "select" ).change(function() {
                  $('.threesixty').data('path', 'img/bmw/test/car{index}.jpg');
                });

 </script>
```

It does not seem to change anything.

When I use:

```
 $( "select" ).change(function() {
                  $('.threesixty').attr('data-path', 'img/bmw/test/car{index}.jpg');
                });
```

It does change the path but still does not show the new set of images.

Any help please?